# how to package only few methods of an API into a Product in APIM?

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I have an API app with multiple routes in it. I am importing these API's into the APIM using the openAPI / swagger definition.

I would like to define two different products for the various API routes in the API.

I see options to define product only at the top level / API level ( that has multiple routes).

Please let me know for any options so that I can create products with different routes of the ONE API app?

Thanks,
Sendhil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any options so that I can create products with different routes of the ONE API app?

In short **No**.

As you have said, the product could only add as API level not operations level.

Unfortunately there is no way to customize this behavior at the moment. You could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management) to promote the feature to be achieved.